# Can I use eigenvalues to find the inverse of a vector?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, inverse, problem-solving

I have two 1D matrices (say dimension 1xn) called **A** and **B**.
Multiplying these:  **A** . **B**  = M. Where M is a scalar.
Knowing **B** and M, can I find **A**?

One cannot take the inverse of a vector, but is it possible to use eigenvalues? as the form for eigenvalues is u=(lambda)v, where u and v are vectors!

Lookinf forward to any helpful answer!

Kind regards,
M

Comment: Knowing $B$, and $M$ does not uniquely specify $A$.  Also nonsquare matrices have *singular values* not eigenvalues.

Comment: Only square matrices have eigenvalues/eigenvectors.

Comment: Hint: consider, for example, $B = (1,1)$ and $M = 1$.

Comment: How can $M$ be a scalar? The product of two matrices always gives a matrix, not a scalar.

Comment: @PrsunBiswas, this is simply the dot product. Consider the operation $$(1\ 2\ 3) \cdot \left( \begin{array}{c} 2 \\ 3\\ 1 \end{array} \right)$$ The result is a $1\times 1$ matrix, which is considered a scalar.

Comment: How can you expect to retrieve $n$ unknowns from a single equation ?

Comment: OP is asking for the existence of a solution. I don't understand why's everybody so concerned with its uniqueness.

Comment: @algebraicpavel the op is asking if he can find $A$ from $A\cdot B = M$. Finding that particular A is where the uniqueness comes in

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $A=\begin{pmatrix}b_1\\b_2\\\vdots\\b_n\end{pmatrix}$ and let $B =\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\\vdots\\x_n\end{pmatrix}$. Then
$$
  A^\top B = M
  \quad\text{or}\quad
a_1x_1+a_2x_2+\ldots+a_nx_n=M.
$$

1. If $a_i=0$ for every $i \in \{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ and $M=0$ then $B$ is an arbitrary vector.
2. If $a_i=0$ for every $i \in \{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ and $M \neq 0$ then the is no $B$ such that the required equality holds.
3. Without loss of generality assume that $a_1 \neq 0$, then $x_1 = \frac{1}{a_1}(M-a_2x_2-\ldots-a_nx_n)$. Here $x_2,\ldots,x_n$ are so called free variables. So,
   $$
     B = \left(\frac{1}{a_1}(M-a_2x_2-\ldots-a_nx_n),x_2,\ldots,x_n\right), 
   \quad\text{ where $x_2,\ldots,x_n \in \mathbb{R}$}.
   $$

Answer (score 0):

You would not be able to uniquely identify $A$. We can see this already by considering two and three dimensions.

$$A\cdot B = \|A\| \|B\| \cos(\theta)$$ where $\theta$ is the angle measured between $A$ and $B$. Note that in two dimensions, if the angle is swapped with $-\theta$ then we have the same result. In three dimensions there are more degrees of freedom.

For example, suppose $A=(1,0)$ and $B=(0,1)$. $A\cdot B =0$ but this is also true for $A'=(-1,0)$ or $A'=(20000,0)$. The dot product can reduce the number of allowable solutions, but unless it is a simple one dimensional system, you cannot determine $A$ from it.